# how to post attachments using Upload Collection - pending

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use the same code wrt official upload collection pending

and in controller where upload is called :

```
onStartUpload: function(oEvent) {
            var oUploadCollection = this.byId("UploadCollection");
            var cFiles = oUploadCollection.getItems().length;
            var uploadInfo = cFiles + " file(s)";

            if (cFiles > 0) {
                oUploadCollection.upload();
                MessageBox.information("Uploaded " + uploadInfo);
            }
        },
```

I have set all required header parameters in `onChange` as:

```
onChange: function(oEvent) {
              var oUploadCollection = oEvent.getSource();
              // Header Token
              var oCustomerHeaderEmailToken = new UploadCollectionParameter({
                  name: "xxxx",
                  value: xxxxx
              });
              // Header Token
              var oCustomerHeaderAuthToken = new UploadCollectionParameter({
                  name: "xxxx",
                  value: "xxxx"
              });  
              oUploadCollection.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderEmailToken);
              oUploadCollection.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderAuthToken);
          },
```

When i tried uploading in BE it gave me error as :

- current request is not a multipart request

Then I tried adding to `onChange` :

```
var oCustomerHeaderContentType = new UploadCollectionParameter({
                  name: "Content-Type",
                  value: "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycXEQN6de4OdX0FBe"
              });
 oUploadCollection.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderContentType);
```

It didn't work even though the error is gone ,

The API works fine and tested in postman but why not with upload collection ? May i know the request sent is a multipart form-data ? Do I need to add any extra parameters ?

- How does a simple back end API (if JAVA/Python) would be to collect files from when upload collection is used ? as there is no `name` to refer in server side like fileuploader and if the request is a multipart in upload collection

hope the experts help me out with this ... thanks :)